# How can i do a bobbly-button with redirect to URL?

Tags: html, redirect

I am trying to make the button redirect to `http://www.hub.test.ru` 500 milliseconds after being clicked, but it's not quite working.

How do I fix it?

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="center">
<button class="bubbly-button" onclick="setTimeout("location.href = 'http://www.hub.test.ru';", 500);">Hub</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What's a bobbly button redirect?

Comment: You need to take out the onclick function separately in script tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` accepts a function and a delay. "`"location.href = 'http://www.hub.test.ru';"`" is not a function.

Instead, wrap it in an arrow function. Your JS should look like this:

```js
setTimeout(()=>{location.href = 'http://www.hub.test.ru'}, 500);
```

Result:

```html
<div class="center">
  <button class="bubbly-button" onclick="setTimeout(()=>{location.href = 'http://www.hub.test.ru'}, 500);">Hub</button>
</div>
```

However, you should not be using inline event handlers. I recommend using `addEventListener`:

```js
document.querySelector('.bubbly-button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{location.href = 'http://www.hub.test.ru'}, 500);
})
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <button class="bubbly-button">Hub</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I cant do this, need to wait 10 minutes after publish, but i will do it soon :)